# OpenWrap problem

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, nuget, openwrap

Am just getting started with [the tutorial](http://codebetter.com/sebastienlambla/2010/10/20/creating-a-new-project-with-openwrap/) and all was going swimmingly until I hit the problem below.

It seems that maybe openWrap has found multiple log4net dll's on my system (which is one reason I need openWrap!) but isn't giving me any clear way to resolve which dll I want.

What must I do?

Cheers,
Berry

## output from command prompt

```
C:\...\Documents\Projects\Library\openWrapProject>o add-wrap log4net  
# OpenWrap v1.0.0.0 ...\Projects\Library\openWrap\Project\wraps\_cache\openwrap-1.0.0.53270092\bin-net35\OpenWrap.dll']  
Wrap descriptor found.  
Project repository present.  
Trying to add package.  
Package log4net not found in repositories.  <=== this is in red  
Did you mean one of the following package?  <=== no choices presented, what to do??
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't added the nuget repository in which log4net lives. See the [wiki](https://github.com/openrasta/openwrap/wiki) for how to do that.

The "Did you mean" instruction should only show up if openwrap can do some guess as to what package you meant.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, which did work. I had no clue from following the tutorial that I needed nuget - perhaps that should be added in there. I also guess in a perfect world that instead of the "Did you mean" that open wrap would realize nuget was missing and offer to get it. Cheers!